# Is there an event in sap.m.PlanningCalendar for the rows loaded?

Tags: sapui5

When using the WorkList (and even Master-detail) templates you have the following event in the `onInit` function:

```js
oTable.attachEventOnce("updateFinished", function() {
    // Restore original busy indicator delay for worklist's table
    oViewModel.setProperty("/tableBusyDelay", iOriginalBusyDelay);
});
```

In the `view.xml` you also have the eventHandler for `updateFinished` which you can set, so that you are able to do stuff when the data is received in your list.

In the `PlanningCalendar` you don't have such an eventhandler, how do we handle these kind of things for such a component?

The logic I'm trying to implement is the following:

```xml
<PlanningCalendar
    id="PC1"
    rows="{
        path: '/DeveloperSet'
    }"
    viewKey="Day"
    busyIndicatorDelay="{planningView>/calendarBusyDelay}"
    noDataText="{planningView>/calendarNoDataText}"
    appointmentSelect="onAppointmentSelect"
    rowSelectionChange="onDeveloperRowChange"
    startDateChange="onStartDateChange">
    <toolbarContent>
        <Title
            text="Title"
            titleStyle="H4" />
        <ToolbarSpacer />
        <Button
            id="bLegend"
            icon="sap-icon://legend"
            type="Transparant"
            press="onShowlegend" />             
    </toolbarContent>
    <rows>
        <PlanningCalendarRow
            icon="{Pic}"
            title="{Name}"
            text="{Role}" /> 
    </rows> 
</PlanningCalendar>
```

I want to load and add the "appointments" only for the visible part (filter on start and endDate) of the calendar, so I want to perform the `oDataModel.read`-calls myself. But the rows (the DeveloperSet) should always remain the same. So I should be able to "wait" until the calendar has the data/rows filled in the calendar and then do my manual calls to retrieve the appointments.

So I need to be able to do something when the data is retrieved, but there is no `updateFinished` event for a calendar?

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

the event "updateFinished" when used in the Table or List is triggered from method updateList, this method handles the update of aggregation "list"

PlanningCalendar does not have an updateRows method, therefore no event "updateFinished"

You could listen to the dataReceived event on the Row binding, if you have one

```
OnInit: function(){
...
  this.oPlanningCalendar = this.byId("PC1")
  var oBinding = oPlanningCalendar.getBinding("rows");
  oBinding.attachDataReceived(this.fnDataReceived, this);
```

else you can extend the control and add your own updateRows method and fire  "updateFinished", the hack test below shows it would work

```
OnInit: function(){
...
  this.oPlanningCalendar = this.byId("PC1");
  this.oPlanningCalendar.updateRows = function(sReason) {
      this.oPlanningCalendar.updateAggregation("rows");

      var oBinding = this.oPlanningCalendar.getBinding("rows");
      if (oBinding) {
         jQuery.sap.log.info("max rows = " + oBinding.getLength() || 0);
      }
  }.bind(this);
```

Comment: Does the dataReceived event fired with jsonModel or only with oDataModel. With JSONModel i see the event is never fired?

Comment: fireDataReceived only gets called in the OData scenarios where data is requested, try the updateRows